# passing data between one page and another

Tags: android, flutter

Good morning everyone, I'm asking for help... I took over an app from two years ago (which worked) and updated everything that was failing.
When passing data between one page and another it gives me the error "The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument", so I solved it by putting "key:null" and the receiving page I put " key? key" instead of "required Key key".
I hope it's the right method... now when the page that receives the values ​​loads it doesn't show me anything but just a gray page.
I don't understand if it's due to the "key: null".
I attach three pages

FIRST PAGE

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:sizer_master/screens/second_page_screen.dart';
import 'package:sizer_master/util/strings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class FirstPageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPageScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstPageScreenState createState() => _FirstPageScreenState();
}

class _FirstPageScreenState extends State<FirstPageScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool _visible = false;

  Future<void> userLogin() async {
    // Showing LinearProgressIndicator.
    setState(() {
      _visible = true;
    });
    var data = {
      'username': _emailController.text,
      'password': _passwordController.text,
    };

    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("https://www.toptradeitaly.com/login_api/user_login2.php"),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
      body: json.encode(data),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //Server response into variable
      print(response.body);
      var msg = jsonDecode(response.body);

      //Check Login Status
      if (msg['loginStatus'] == true) {
        setState(() {
          //hide progress indicator
          _visible = false;
        });

        // Navigate to Home Screen
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SecondPageScreen(
                      uname: msg['userInfo']['USR_USERD'],
                      unid: msg['userInfo']['UID'],
                      nutel: msg['userInfo']['USR_NUTEL'],
                      cdana: msg['userInfo']['USR_CDANA'],
                      key: null,
                    )));
      } else {
        setState(() {
          //hide progress indicator
          _visible = false;

          //Show Error Message Dialog
          showMessage(msg["message"]);
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        //hide progress indicator
        _visible = false;

        //Show Error Message Dialog
        showMessage("Error during connecting to Server.");
      });
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> showMessage(String _msg) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(_msg),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizerUtil.orientation == Orientation.portrait
        ? _widPortrait()
        : _widLandScape();
  }

  Widget _widPortrait() {
    return Material(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: 100.h,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              _widMainImg(),
              Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                children: [_widTitle(), _widDesc()],
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _widMainImg() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.w),
      child: Image.asset('images/mizuno.png', height: 50.h),
    );
  }

  _widTitle() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0.w),
      child: Form(
        //key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: _emailController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email',
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.sp, color: Colors.black),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter your email';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 2.0.h), // Aggiunge spazio verticale tra i campi
            TextFormField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.sp, color: Colors.black),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter your password';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 3.0.h), // Aggiunge spazio verticale tra i campi
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: userLogin,
              child: const Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    /*return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.5.h),
      child: Text(Strings.APP_NAME,
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.sp, color: Colors.black),
          )),
    );*/
  }

  _widDesc() {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.w, left: 10.w, top: 2.h),
        child: Text(
          Strings.APP_DESC,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle:
                TextStyle(height: 1.3, fontSize: 13.sp, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ));
  }

//landscape
  _widLandScape() {
    return Material(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: 100.h,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              _widMainImgLand(),
              Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                children: [_widTitleLand(), _widDescLand()],
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _widMainImgLand() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.w),
      child: Image.asset('images/mizuno.png', height: 25.h),
    );
  }

  _widTitleLand() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0.w),
      child: Form(
        //key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: _emailController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email',
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.sp, color: Colors.black),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter your email';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 2.0.h), // Aggiunge spazio verticale tra i campi
            TextFormField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.sp, color: Colors.black),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter your password';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 3.0.h), // Aggiunge spazio verticale tra i campi
            ElevatedButton(
              //onPressed: () {},
              onPressed: userLogin,
              child: const Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    /*return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0.h),
      child: Text(Strings.APP_NAME,
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.sp, color: Colors.black),
          )),
    );*/
  }

  _widDescLand() {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.w, left: 25.w, top: 1.5.h),
        child: Text(
          Strings.APP_DESC,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle:
                TextStyle(height: 1.3, fontSize: 13.sp, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

SECOND PAGE

```
import 'package:sizer_master/screens/first_page_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import '../common/profile_info_big_card.dart';

class SecondPageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String uname;
  final String unid;
  final String nutel;
  final String cdana;

  const SecondPageScreen(
      { //required Key key,
      Key? key,
      required this.uname,
      required this.unid,
      required this.nutel,
      required this.cdana})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Area Agenti'),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 218, 104),
        elevation: 0.0, // Rimuove l'elevazione
        automaticallyImplyLeading:
            false, // Rimuove la freccia di navigazione a sinistra
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const FirstPageScreen()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0.h),
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 218, 104),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ClipOval(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 20.0.w,
                      height: 20.0.w,
                      color: Colors.white10,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'images/affari.png',
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          width: 18.0.w,
                          height: 18.0.w,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                      height: 8.0), // Spazio tra l'immagine e il testo
                  Text(
                    uname,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0.sp),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    nutel,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0.sp),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0.h),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GridView.count(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 2.0.w,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 2.0.h,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ProfileInfoBigCard(
                          firstText: "Contatti",
                          icon: Icons.contact_mail,
                          uname: uname,
                          unid: unid,
                          cdana: cdana,
                          nutel: nutel,
                          page: '1',
                          key: null,
                        ),
                        const ProfileInfoBigCard(
                          firstText: "Vendite",
                          icon: Icons.shopping_cart,
                          uname: '',
                          unid: '',
                          page: '',
                          cdana: '',
                          nutel: '',
                          //key: ValueKey(key),
                          //key: null,
                        ),
                        const ProfileInfoBigCard(
                          firstText: "Credito",
                          icon: Icons.euro,
                          uname: '',
                          unid: '',
                          page: '',
                          cdana: '',
                          nutel: '',
                          //key: null,
                          // key: ValueKey(key),
                        ),
                        const ProfileInfoBigCard(
                          firstText: "Notifiche",
                          icon: Icons.notifications,
                          uname: '',
                          unid: '',
                          page: '',
                          cdana: '',
                          nutel: '',
                          //key: null,
                          //key: ValueKey(key),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ProfileInfoBigCard

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:sizer_master/screens/fourth_page_screen.dart';
import '../screens/list_contatti_screen.dart';

class ProfileInfoBigCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String firstText;
  final IconData icon;
  final String uname;
  final String unid;
  final String cdana;
  final String nutel;
  final String page;

  const ProfileInfoBigCard(
      { //required Key key,
      Key? key,
      required this.firstText,
      required this.icon,
      required this.uname,
      required this.unid,
      required this.page,
      required this.cdana,
      required this.nutel})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (page == "1") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ListContattiScreen(
                uname: uname,
                unid: unid,
                cdana: cdana,
                nutel: nutel,
                key: null,
                //key: ValueKey(key),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (page == "2") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FourthPageScreen(),
            ),
          );
        } else if (page == "3") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FourthPageScreen(),
            ),
          );
        } else if (page == "4") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FourthPageScreen(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
          elevation: 5,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 16.0,
              top: 16,
              bottom: 24,
              right: 16,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    firstText,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0.sp),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(icon, size: 24.0.sp),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely the grey screen has nothing to do with passing a key. You don’t need to pass ´key: null´ as this is the default value. It is also recommended to use the ´super.key´ notation (code style). However the way you solved it should work too. Therefore you problem is probably caused by something else.

Comment: @jarinox I updated the whole app and changed the key (key? key instead of required Key key), so could it be some command that no longer does its job? and how can I understand where, given that I immediately see the gray screen...

Comment: I would try to use the [debugger](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/debugging) to understand the logical flow of the application and what widgets are actually used. In VS Code or Android Studio you can easily set breakpoints and inspect any variable at runtime.

Comment: I did the debugging and solved it.... the problem was here " unid: msg['userInfo']['UID'] ", on the database it is uid... it gave uppercase / lowercase problems... thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
ProfileInfoBigCard({
  super.key, // <- Correct
  // ...
});
```

Rather than having this:

```
ProfileInfoBigCard({
  { //required Key key,
  Key? key,
  // ...
})
: super(key: key);
```

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but super key is already there...

' const ProfileInfoBigCard(
      { //required Key key,
      Key? key,
      //super.key,
      required this.firstText,
      required this.icon,
      required this.uname,
      required this.unid,
      required this.page,
      required this.cdana,
      required this.nutel})
      : super(key: key);  '

Comment: It doesn't even work as you say....

Comment: As far as I understood from your question is that you don't want to struggle with key when calling another widget or page, then my suggestion was to use super.key, because this line of code omits the key argument entirely as the type of the key argument was not explicitly defined, allowing it to be null by default.

Comment: Don't forget to remove **: super(key: key);**

Comment: it does not work

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: doesn't show me anything but just a gray page....

Comment: Then you problem is mostly caused by something else, check which widget is using the gray color and investigate from there, it could be a navigation issue, I'm not sure!

Comment: the only place where I use gray is FIRST PAGE

`  _widDescLand() {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.w, left: 25.w, top: 1.5.h),
        child: Text(
          Strings.APP_DESC,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle:
                TextStyle(height: 1.3, fontSize: 13.sp, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ));
  } `